# tf not found using python in ros noetic

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/tf2%20and%20time%20%28Python%29)  to find a transformation between 2 frames using Python in ROS Noetic, but I can't get it even though I'm sure the tf exists because I can find it in the terminal.

Here is what I get in the terminal:

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /tool0
    At time 1667484434.367
    - Translation: [-0.197, 0.704, 0.486]
    - Rotation: in Quaternion [1.000, 0.000, -0.000, -0.000]
                in RPY (radian) [-3.141, 0.001, 0.000]
                in RPY (degree) [-179.967, 0.041, 0.028]
    At time 1667484434.967
    - Translation: [-0.197, 0.704, 0.486]
    - Rotation: in Quaternion [1.000, 0.000, -0.000, -0.000]
                in RPY (radian) [-3.141, 0.001, 0.000]
                in RPY (degree) [-179.967, 0.041, 0.028]
    At time 1667484435.967
    - Translation: [-0.197, 0.704, 0.486]
    - Rotation: in Quaternion [1.000, 0.000, -0.000, -0.000]
                in RPY (radian) [-3.141, 0.001, 0.000]
                in RPY (degree) [-179.967, 0.041, 0.028]
```

Here is a minimal code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import tf2_ros

class ourbot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ourbot, self).__init__()

        moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
        rospy.init_node("get_tf", anonymous=True)

def main():
    try:    
        demorobot = ourbot()
        
        tfBuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
        listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tfBuffer)

        try:
            trans = tfBuffer.lookup_transform('base_link', 'tool0', rospy.Duration(3.0))
            pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(pose_robot, trans)
            print(pose_transformed)
        except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException):
            print('not found')     
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        return
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408932/tf-not-found-using-python-in-ros-noetic/) by [robra](https://answers.ros.org/users/121281/robra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have two problems with this code:

1. The third argument to lookup_transform() is a rospy.Time object, as in time-of-day, not a Duration object. Try using rospy.Time(0).
2. Your tfBuffer needs some time to actually receive the messages from the /tf topic. You must either 1) explicitly specify timeout=Duration(3.0), or 2) insert a big-enough delay before the call, or 3) loop calling the tfBuffer.can_transform() method until the tfBuffer says it is ready to provide the information.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robra](https://answers.ros.org/users/121281/robra/) on 2022-11-04**:
Thank you, I actually forgot to update the question, but I had already changed this line: `trans = tfBuffer.lookup_transform('base_link', 'tool0', rospy.Duration(3.0))` to `trans = tfBuffer.lookup_transform('base_link', 'tool0', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(3.0))` as in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/tf2%20and%20time%20%28Python%29) but that didn't work either. However, using the `rospy.Time(0)` instead of `rospy.Time.now(),` works!